# scp certain files only

Tags: linux, unix, rsync, scp

I am trying to copy changed files to godaddy via ssh. Godaddy is terrible and so they of course do not allow rsync. I can use scp, but I really only want to copy changed files. I don't think this is possible, so I was wondering if perhaps I could scp only all php files.

There are a lot of sub directories, though, so I need to use the -r option.

**Is there a way I can use scp to copy all files with extension `php`, recursively?  like this:**

`scp -r -name "*php" /local/html/ user@server:/home/html/`
(does not work)

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
//on local machine
$ find ./source

source/1.php
source/2.php
source/sub
source/sub/3.php
source/sub/4.php
source/sub/DONT-copy.txt
source/sub/DONT-copy.png
source/sub/sub2
source/sub/sub2/5.php
source/sub/sub2/6.php

//command to copy the files
$ [scp command here]

//on remote server
$ find ./destination

destination/1.php
destination/2.php
destination/sub
destination/sub/3.php
destination/sub/4.php
destination/sub/sub2
destination/sub/sub2/5.php
destination/sub/sub2/6.php
```

**THIS DOES NOT WORK**

```
//on local machine
$ find ./source

source/1.php
source/2.php
source/sub
source/sub/3.php
source/sub/4.php
source/sub/DONT-copy.txt
source/sub/DONT-copy.png
source/sub/sub2
source/sub/sub2/5.php
source/sub/sub2/6.php

//command to copy the files
$ cd source; scp -r *.php user@remote:/destination 

//on remote server
$ find ./destination

destination/1.php
destination/2.php
```

Perhaps we could try and use find, as well, but I'm pretty sure this *will not work as is*:

```
find ./source -name "*.php" -exec scp {} user@remote:{} \;
```

That won't work because I don't think you can use multiple `{}` operators in find.

Also, it might be tricky to get the paths to line up on the remote server, for example if find was returning `/users/johndoe/documents/source/1.php` and you wanted it to end up at `/home/jane/www/destination/1.php` on the remote server.

Comment: Is it possible that you run a command (via ssh) on the remote server? If so, you can tar the files locally and do a `cat phpfiles.tar | ssh user@remote "cd destination && tar cf -"` to transfer all you files in one run.

Comment: Did you actually tried your last find command with multiple `{}` tokens? I looks promising (you _can_ use multiple `{}`), perhaps you need to specify `user@remote:~/{}` as destination.

Comment: Oups, this question was nearly two year ago... I am wondering why it showed on top of the questions rigth now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's what I do when a host ony allows pushing stuff, and no rsync:

- create a "shadow" directory on your local machine to resemble the
  target structure
- use `rsync` to push to this shadow directory, and
  capture the output (there's `--log-file` if you want to script it)
- from the `rsync` output, determine the files you need to delete, or
  push and make a list
- maybe (depends on the way you push): create a package from the files that need to be changed only
- start your push tool - ftp, scp, whatever - and
  let it run on the files from the list

Answer (score 1):

Can you not do `scp -r *.php destination` ?

Comment: but will that copy all *.php files in subdirectories as well?

Comment: @cwd: What is your exact requirement?

Comment: updated the question

Comment: I am still not sure what you are asking here. what files you want to copy from `/local/html`? all *.php files? only changed `*.php` files? what does argument `-name` mean?

Comment: `-name` is the paramater that rsync uses to filter only php files. i would ideally like to copy only changed files (like rsync) but since rsync is not available I would like to just copy php files only (to save bandwidth). Does that make sense? I guess I could do a `find -exec scp` command but I would need to grab the basepath and make sure that gets added to the destination argument as well. just seems like there should be an easy way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

scp -r user@ip:/data/files/*.php /tmp/files/